# Checkstyle RegexpHeader not detecting regex properly

Tags: java, regex, checkstyle

I'm trying to add a checkstyle config for how code files should begin in the codebase. The format I want can be described by a pattern in java - `^package .*\n\n.*`. However, this pattern doesn't seem to work when I use it with `RegexpHeader`. Here is my config -

```
<module name="RegexpHeader">
    <property name="header" value="^package .*\n\n.*"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
</module>
```

And it doesn't seem to fail for this -

```
package my.checkstyle.frustrations;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class ShouldFail
{
}
```

I have created a sample project [here](https://github.com/vivekrao1985/regexpproblems).

Comment: Wild guess: Could it be that checkstyle is removing the comment before doing the regex check?

Comment: Please share your problem is format that checkstyle team recommend to report problems http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/report_issue.html#How_to_report_a_bug if not possible to reproduce  by CLI, so problem is is plugin configuration

Comment: @RomanIvanov - I submitted new bug here - https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/4735

Comment: I think the problem is in ```AbstractHeaderCheck```. If the input header regex has two or more consecutive newlines, then the default behavior is to accept everything, when it should really be checking to make sure the line is empty. I managed to bypass this issue by defining my regex as ```^package\n^$```. So basically ```^package``` enforces that the first line of a code file must begin with package and ```\n^$``` enforces that 2nd line is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this check is not meant to be used the way I'm using it. It is supposed to be used for headers only, prior to any code in the file (including package declarations). I did however manage to hack it to get it to work for my use case by changing my regex to `^package\n^$`.

I also tried using `EmptyLineSeparatorCheck` with the `PACKAGE_DEF` token, but it didn't work either because that check ignores commented lines. If anyone knows of another check I could use that's meant for my use-case please let me know.